# How to boot Windows 7 in verbose mode?

Tags: windows-7, boot

Recently my Win 7 installation takes a very long time to boot up and in order for me to detect the problem I need to boot Windows in verbose mode.
Now I need windows to dump everything it's doing in the boot process on monitor screen. I wonder how can this be done?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Over at [How-To Geek](http://www.howtogeek.com/?post_type=post&p=32477) there is a post on how to do this.

Hit Start, type `msconfig`, to get to the System Configuration window below

[image: System Config]

Select the `Boot` tab and check the `OS boot information`.  Checking the log may also be useful to read after booting.

Comment: The log will be called Ntbtlog.txt is foundin the %SystemRoot% folder.

Comment: @Edwin The link also has a number of other useful tools to troubleshoot boot time issues.  Check it out :)