# How to boot in verbose boot for Windows 10?

Tags: boot, windows-10

I am always looking for as much information when it comes to turning the computer on and off. This time I am interesting in getting the driver information like you use to get in Windows 7 during Safe Boot.

[How to boot Windows 7 in verbose mode?](https://superuser.com/questions/448067/how-to-boot-windows-7-in-verbose-mode)

This question gives an answer to exactly what I am looking for however only works in Windows 7. I tried it for Windows 10 and I got exactly what I got last time *(Boot Screen)*

## My Question

How do I get the driver information like the other question but for Windows 10? Have Microsoft stopped this from happening?

Comment: if you have any slowdown, you should capture a boot trace wit xbootmgr: http://pastebin.com/CYGqRZXE

Answer (score 8):

#### How to boot in verbose boot for Windows 10?

> 1. Start > Run > Type "regedit" (without the quotes) and select from the list.
> 2. Find the key:
>
>    `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System`
> 3. You might want to export this as a backup first or note down the settings if there's already a "VerboseStatus" field. In most cases, it
>      won't be there yet.
> 4. Right-click under that and create a New > DWORD Value.
> 5. Type `VerboseStatus` and double-click that new key, giving it the value data set to `1`.
>
> Next time you reboot, Windows will now give you verbose startup,
>   shutdown, logon, and logoff status messages.

Source [Problems since Windows 10](https://steamcommunity.com/discussions/forum/11/496879865901748208/)

Comment: I tried that however still doesn't work. I do get verbose for shutdown, logon and other though. I have just thought that it could be because of disk checking which I skip each time. I will let it run soon and comment back what happened.

Comment: @RACING121 Any update on your last comment?

Comment: Still not working, must be a problem on my PC

Answer (score 4):

You enabled it exactly how you enabled it in Windows 7.

Search for "*System Configuration*" on the **Start Menu** and enable "*OS Boot information*".

[image]

Comment: I realized only after I hit submit that, this is an identical answer, but **it worked for me** so I am keeping it.  Feel free to downvote if you want.

Comment: I won't downvote because if it worked for you then it might be a problem with my PC. I will wait for more answers.

Answer (score 2):

The options are still there, just much more hidden... When I played with it it seemed to give less information though (could have just been me though). I think this is what your are looking for, ignore the first part and scroll down to Enable Verbose Service Startup/Shutdown Messages, the same method works:

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/32477/use-verbose-boot-messages-to-troubleshoot-windows-startup-problems/

You can also use a program called Ultimate Windows Tweaker http://www.thewindowsclub.com/ultimate-windows-tweaker-4-windows-10
There is an option under User Accounts called Enable Verbose Logon Messages.

Comment: *How to boot Windows 7 in verbose mode?

This question gives an answer to exactly what I am looking for however only works in Windows 7. I tried it for Windows 10 and I got exactly what I got last time (Boot Screen)*

Answer (score 2):

This functionality seem to be broken. Best thing you can do is vote for Microsoft to bring it back on Windows Feedback Hub:

- [for normal users](https://aka.ms/L3lndo)
- [for insiders](https://aka.ms/G8nlm7).

Answer (score 0):

You can get a few messages during start and login with the verbosity setting suggested in @DavidPostill's answer. For that, run this in an admin command prompt or Powershell:

```
reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System\" /v "verbosestatus" /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
reg delete "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System\" /v "DisableStatusMessages"
```

(The second command will usually give an error because that registry key was not defined. But the command is needed to remove it in case it was defined)

This adds very little verbosity and is usually not what you need, but well, it's easy and doesn't hurt.

If you need more, there is only the boot options as described in [Ramhound's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1006853/53547)